# How to make a Azure Pipeline Build task mandatory?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

is there any way, I can make below tasks mandatory so that a user cannot disable it under Build Pipeline(CI) in Azure DevOps

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are the owner of the organization, you can manage it through the settings.

Navigate to **`Your Project -> Pipeline -> Manage Security`** and probably you need to restrict the user from editing the pipeline

There are [**various policies**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops) available which you can play around.

Comment: How will this apply to only one task in the pipeline? Isn't this for the entire pipeline. I think the idea is to allow the developer to be able to delete all tasks but the one requiring the scan.

Answer (score 2):

You can develop a Pipeline decorator extension and then install it to your organization. Pipeline decorators let you add steps to the beginning and end of every pipeline job.

To view more details, you can see "[**Use a decorator to inject steps into a pipeline**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-pipeline-decorator?view=azure-devops)".

Normally, only the **Organization Owner** or **Project Collection Administrators** can add or delete the extensions on the organization. So, other users are not able to remove the decorators from the pipelines.